# Adapter class vs toXXX() method in data class

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, pojo

I have a scenario where I want to convert an object to a service request object type to call a service.

I have a data object like this:

```
class Data {
  int val;
  ...
}
```

I want to convert this object into a service request object lets say DataRequest. I'm thinking of these two options: 
1. Have a `toDataRequest()` method in the Data class itself.

```
class Data {
  int val;
  ...

  public DataRequest toDataRequest() {
    ..
  }
}
```

2. Have a separate class `DataAdapter`, and have adapt method in it, which returns the `DataRequest` object.

```
class DataAdapter {
  public DataRequest adapt(Data data) {
    ... 
  }
}
```

I'm leaning towards the 1st, as it helps reducing the number of classes. I'd love to hear, what is a general recommendation for this use-case?

Comment: or, `DataRequest.create(Data)` ?

Comment: This would work if you have access to the service layer class `DataRequest`. But unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: a purist would frown upon the 1st option, since a lower-layer class has a dependency on a higher-layer class. that may cause problems, but probably ok in your app. This is just a convenience method that we need to put *somewhere*; the dependency is superfacial.

Comment: got it! makes sense.

Comment: Decisions like this should be based on what makes a better OO abstraction, not on micro-optimizations like reducing the number of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your architecture. Often you have a service layer and at least a persistence layer. The service layer is above the persistence layer and usually the architecture only allows accesses from a higher layer to a lower layer. E.g.

```
 +----------------------------+
 |       service layer        |  // request object is placed here
 +----------------------------+
              | depends on
              V
 +----------------------------+
 |    persistence layer       |  // Data object is placed here
 +----------------------------+
```

So when your `Data` object has a method `public DataRequest toDataRequest()` it has a dependency to `DataRequest` and this means a lower layer has a dependency to a higher layer. This is usually not what you want.

So if you use your `DataAdapter` (also known as DataMapper) and place it in the service layer you will respect the architecture shown above.

You can also implement the mapping logic in the `DataRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it!

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to do the first option. Let's take the String class as an example. Many classes can be turned into Strings **if the writers of the class deem it useful**. The writers of the class will just have to add a toString method to the end of their class. They will not have to ask Oracle to add a factory method for Strings based on the class that these developers wrote. This would not only just be ridiculously annoying for Oracle to maintain, but it would also just be awful because the overhead on the String object would skyrocket with all the factory methods.